# Publishing dependency jars to artifactory along with the main artifact through gradle

Tags: dependencies, gradle, artifactory

I have a project A that I build and deploy to artifactory using gradle. A depends on lib.jar file. In A/build.gradle I have  `compile files("lib.jar")`.

When I do gradle artifactoryPublish there is no lib.jar in artifacotry. Is there a way to automatically include lib.jar along with A.jar?

I have a project B that depends on A and also references lib.jar. In B/build.gradle I use `compile(group:'a', name: 'A', version: '1')`.

I need to pull lib.jar as well. The obvious solution would be to add lib.jar to artifacotry manually. And reference it just as A, but is there a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Search for "file artifacts" in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: Thanks, I posted my question about this approach below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare it as an artifact for it to be included.

```
def myLib = file('lib.jar')

artifacts {
   archives myLib
}
```

Another solution is to upload it to a repository as a separate jar example `foo:Bar:1` and then use dependencies to build `a:A:1` and upload `a:A:1` to the repository.

If you then use `a:A:1` as a dependency to build `b:B:1` the pom of `a:A:1` will automatically refer to your lib.jar `foo:Bar:1` and it will be pulled down.

Comment: How do I refer to lib.jar artifact in B (when using `artifacts`)? I see that in artifactory I have lib-1 loaded, but it is under A, so I can not use a:A:1.

Comment: You can refer to it as `a:A:1@lib.jar`

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution I merged myLib.jar into A.jar:

```
task addJar(type: Copy) {
    FileTree f = zipTree('lib.jar')
    from f
    into 'build/classes/main'
}

jar.dependsOn(addJar)
```